# Check in which Image in a dataset I get the warning libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile while using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have a dataset, it has 2500 images. To access each of them and apply normalization, I loop over the images:

```
for path_to_image in dataset:
      image = cv2.imread(path_to_image)
      # rest of the code follows
```

While running the code I get this error/warning  `libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile while using OpenCV`

I tried to use some tricks to get the approximate value of iteration where the image is not being read properly but it did not work.

Is there any way I can obtain the variable `path_to_image` where I get this error?

What I was thinking is there must be a variable that stores some information about the warning.

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Assuming they exist as 2500 PNG files in your filesystem, you could try running `pngcheck` on them, just in Terminal.

Comment: Sorry for not writing this before but all the files are stored as .jpg

Comment: That cannot be. Your warning is from `libpng`. If you are on Linux, you can run `file *.jpg` and see if you have a PNG that happens to have a `JPG` extension.

Comment: It works, thanks! The command I used was `pngcheck -q *.png` where -q is to report only errors